# Not able to pass reference variable of an object in actual argument in the case of using this as formal argument

Tags: java, java-8

Here is the following code:

```
class Sample{

  private void display(Sample this, int x){
    System.out.println(x);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sample s = new Sample();
    s.display(10);
  }
}
```

The above code is working fine if I do not pass reference variable of Sample class as an actual argument i.e. `s.display(10)`.

I am aware of the fact that from `JDK 8` onwards we are allowed to pass this as parameter(formal arguments) and that too as the first argument and compiler internally inserts `Sample this` as first argument as parameter(or formal argument) i.e. `private void display(Sample this.....` if I do not write `Sample this` as pararemeter (formal argument) explicitly.

But if I try to pass reference variable as argument(actual argument) i.e. `s.display(s, 10)`, then the code doesn't compile even when both the actual and formal arguments are same.
eg:

```
class Sample{

  private void display(Sample this, int x){
    System.out.println(x);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sample s = new Sample();
    s.display(s, 10);
  }
}
```

What's the reason behind of not compiling the above code?

Comment: `Sample this` is not a *real* parameter, it's a *receiver parameter* which is pointless (i.e. effectively ignored) when used like this. It exists only to allow annotations on the type, if desired and has no other effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s.display(s, 10);` doesn't compile because the compiler internally passes the `this` reference to `s` as well, that's why `s.display(10)` works - the compiler makes it to be similar to `Sample.display(s, 10)` while `s.display(s, 10)` would be more like `Sample.display(s, s, 10)`.

Think of instance methods as being static methods which implicitly get the `this` formal parameter. Now try adding another method like `static void display(Sample that, int x)`. Which one should be called when you're calling `s.display(s, 10)`? You might assume it's the instance method that takes `this` but it's actually the static method that's called (albeit the compiler would warn about a static method being accessed in a non-static way).

Additionally, what would happen if you were allowed to call `display(Sample this, int x)` as `s.display(s, 10)`? You could as well call `s.display(new Sample(), 10)` and now you'd have a conflict since `this` wouldn't refer to `s` anymore. That's why this is not allowed.

Comment: `Think of instance methods as being static methods which implicitly get the this formal parameter.` Your statement can't be imagined as `this` doesn't play role in case of static methods as they are called using class name only and `this` will never be there as the formal parameter, but I got your point though. I thought that if I pass reference variable i.e. `s` in the actual arguments explicitly, then the compiler won't insert `s` implicitly. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @AkshayaAmar you're welcome. As for the comparison: just replace the term "this" with "that" and the methods will be very similar (not counting overloads). In fact, if you'd have a method reference that uses the class as the first parameter you _could_ assign a static method with an explicit parameter or an instance method with just the formal or implicit parameter (and if both exist the compiler would complain), i.e. a `BiConsumer<Sample , Integer>` could take `void display(int x)`, `void display(Sample this, int x)` or `static void display(Sample that, int x)`.